# Google Test compilation error from gtest-all.cc

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, googletest

I'm trying to compile google test with my test cases, but couldn't. I have not made any changes to gtest_main.cc or gtest-all.cc files, even then I'm not able to compile these files.
I'm getting the following error:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/include -I../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0 -c ../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc
In file included from ../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest.cc:35,
             from ../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc:42:
../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/include/gtest/gtest-spi.h:52: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/ext/atomicity.h:34,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/ios_base.h:41,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/ios:43,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/ostream:40,
             from ../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest.cc:46,
             from ../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc:42:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr.h:30: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr.h:30: error: expected declaration before end of line
```

But I could compile gtest_main.cc without any error:

```
   g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/include -I../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0 -c ../../../ext/gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc
```

Couldn't find any help from google as well ..!! Thanks for any help, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to install it manually following this post:[Arturo Ruiz Mañas' response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295876/cmake-cannot-find-a-googletest-required-library).
It didn't work so I tired the other option also in that post but I already added the headers in `/usr/local/include`.

Check if there are old headers added and try @detrick version of installation.